# "Пустой" listView

Tags: java, android

```
ListView listView = (ListView)container.findViewById(R.id.listView);
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
String[] datasource = {"aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"};
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.text1, datasource);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Когда запускаю приложение, появляется ошибка `java.lang.NullPointerException` в строке `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Вот xml фрагмента, на котором `ListView`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.andrew.mpd.fragments.OneFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</ScrollView>
```

Что я упустил или сделал не так?

Comment: Что за `container`? Почему он до загрузки разметки? И никогда не оборачивайте ListView в ScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
ListView listView = (ListView)rootView .findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

И никогда не оборачивайте ListView в ScrollView

Comment: Почему не оборачивать в ScrollView?

Comment: @andrew, вы можете просто попробовать) У вас будет отображаться только один элемент списка, т.к. сам ListView - скролящийся элемент разметки и конфликтует со ScrollView при вычислении высоты отдельных элементов. Это можно обойти грязным хаком, но лучше не пробовать это делать.